# Where is the hole in this argument asserting the constructibility of all regular polygons?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, proof-explanation, polygons, geometric-construction

Some engineers have a so-called "general" method for constructing any (regular) polygon with the classical instruments only, given the length of its side (they *may* recognise that it appears to be inaccurate for some polygons, say for the $7$-gon, but this is beside the point of my question, as I hope you see later on).

They proceed by constructing a segment $AB$ equal to the given length, then bisecting it with a perpendicular line intersecting $AB$ at its midpoint $M$. From one end of the segment, say $A$, an angle $S\widehat AM=45°$ is constructed, where $S$ is the intersection point of the other arm of the angle and the perpendicular bisector. On point $B$, an angle $H\widehat BM=60°$ is similarly constructed. The points $S$ and $H$ are *clearly* the circumcentres of a square and a hexagon of side $AB$ respectively. *All is fine up till now.*

**Then they proceed to bisect the segment $HS$ to get its midpoint $P$, which they assert to be the circumcentre of a pentagon of side $AB$.** Since $HP=PS$, they mark off points above $H$ using the distance $HP$, and claim that these points give the circumcentres of any $n$-gon with $n\ge7$.

Of course, this is impossible according to the theorem of constructibility of Gauss. For example (and from now I shall focus on the $7$-gon wlog), the regular heptagon cannot be so constructed. It follows that even though all the steps of the construction (with one possible exception) appear to be justified, there must be something wrong with the reasoning somewhere. In particular, one suspects the highlighted step above as a possible source of an extraneous assumption, but I cannot quite pinpoint why this step is not justified. What exactly is the problem with this step (or any other in the argument, assuming it is not indeed this step as I think) in clear terms? In particular,

> how can one make such an engineer see that there is something wrong with this construction, *by pointing out some flaw in one or more of the steps therein?*

Thank you.

Comment: For those looking for a diagram: https://imgur.com/a/7xNZkXk. I'm not sure if this is the type of answer you're looking for - but geometry software or a little trigonometry shows that the angles aren't correct, but for $n=5$ or $n=7$ they're not far off: for $n=8$ the angle constructed is around $44.18^\circ$ instead of the correct $45^\circ$.

Comment: You could, by trigonometry, compute the distance from M to the circumcenters for 4-, 5-, 6-gons (as decimals assuming say, that AB has length 1) and hopefully see that the midpoint between the 4- and 6- circumcenters is not the circumcenter of the pentagon.

Comment: An *engineer* should be able to determine (perhaps by careful measurement of a large enough figure) that $$\angle APB \approx 72.412^\circ \neq 72^\circ = \frac15\cdot 360^\circ$$ so that the construction already fails for $n=5$.

Comment: "how can one make an engineer see .... which they can easily grasp?"  Well, an engineer could just as easily ask "how can one make a mathematician see that nobody practical should care if it is not exact as in the real world accuracy only exists to a margin of error; how can we put it in practical terms they can grasp that they are wasting time and their lives on things that can't matter". Let's not condescend, shall we? Engineers know damned well it is an approximation. They just don't see why it should matter.  (And to be fair, you haven't explained why it should.)

Comment: @fleablood Are you suggesting that engineers care to know about Gauss's constructibility theorem? And I asked because I know people who assume that the construction is correct because other similar constructions (e.g., for the first few polygons) are correct.

Comment: @Ned Thank you very much for your contribution. In retrospect it effectively gets at what I wanted. (I however did not get to check out the suggestion until now, hence my late reply). If you wish you could make it an answer so the question will be closed.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut What I mean is that one could justify them if one wanted to, writing them out as elaborately as required until we get to commonly accepted axioms. It is easy to see this. The construction involves very elementary steps -- bisection of segments and constructible angles, for example (which anyone who has studied elementary euclidean geometry knows can be shown).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I'm trying to see what is unclear, but maybe the problem here is that you're missing a few quantifiers. I did **not** say **all** the steps could be justified. Specifically, the steps up to (and *not* including) the construction of $P$ can clearly be justified, no?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut That's interesting. You do not think, for example, that $S$ is the circumcentre of a square of side $AB$?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut We are talking about a purported method for constructing an arbitrary $n$-gon with $n\ge 4$. No one is changing anything. You claimed that the steps don't lead to any such $n$-gon (without proof!) and I said it does lead to at least one such $n$-gon (for example the square of side $AB$). It seems you do not always understand what I write.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Every one can now see who's changing his words. Previously you said it produces no $n$-gon, and now you're making two exceptions, see? To say this to you for the umpteenth time -- I already know it doesn't work. This is not what the question is about. And this discussion originates from trying to clarify what I meant by one of the sentences in the OP, but now you've disingenuously twisted it into another thing. As for Blue's **second** answer, I do not accept it only because (as I've explained to him) it includes an irrelevancy. (**Continued.**)

Comment: ...There is a possibility that @Ned will post his comment as an answer (which precedes that of Blue historically). I will only accept Blue's answer in the case that Ned does not convert his comment into an answer in reasonable time or no other answer comes close to these two.

Comment: @Allawonder: It's not so much that the construction provides valid $4$-gon and $6$-gon centers, but that it *builds* upon them. The centers of a square and hexagon are "easy" cases; the construction's value is in providing (approximations of) the "hard" cases.

Comment: @Allawonder: As for disqualifying my answer for containing "an irrelevancy" ... I may be answering your question, but I'm *addressing* the Math.SE community. My epilogue puts my two answers in context for the general reader.

Comment: @Blue On the contrary, the only thing your epilogue does is to suggest (indeed imply) that your first answer is relevant to the question, which it demonstrably isn't.

Comment: @Blue The construction indeed (trivially) provides valid centres for at least one $n$-gon, since the steps are part of it. I insisted upon it merely for correctness and precision. One doesn't usually discard the empty set even though it doesn't do any real work outside of foundations.

Comment: Glad I could be of service. I'm too lazy to actually write out the trig calculations, so I'll just leave it as a comment .

Comment: @Ned That's OK. Though there's a verbose answer I could have otherwise accepted, it is even worse than Blue's second answer in assuming the engineer in the OP did not know that the construction may be inaccurate. So, I am left with Blue, like it or not. Thanks all. All the answers were useful in some way, and I see that the fault can be blamed on our penchant to linearise. I wonder where this intuition came from -- but that, of course, doesn't belong to MSE. Once again, thanks all.

Comment: @Allawonder: If my (or anyone's) answer is unsatisfying to you, then you should not accept it. A question without an accepted answer will auto-bump to the top of the question queue from time to time, so you may eventually get a response that you can accept without holding your nose. Best regards ...

Comment: @Blue Thanks for the suggestion. Although the answers (or rather the additional baggage some added on) were not (completely) satisfying, they were very useful in leading me to seeing what *is* wrong with the second bisection in the construction. Therefore, I think it serves little use to keep the question open further. Hence my acceptance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a comment to an answer, as requested. I'll paraphrase and expand the thoughts.

---

OP asks: "[W]hy [...] is it that [the midpoint of the circumcentres of the square and hexagon] is not the circumcentre of the regular pentagon [...]?"

I respond: It's just *not* ... and there's no reason to even suspect that it *should* be. (OP counters that there *is* a reason: "intuition", and its fondness for the mean. Be that as it may ...)

The issue can be settled by explicit calculation. The distance from the center to the side (of length $1$) of a regular $n$-gon (ie, the [apothem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apothem)) is given by

$$\frac{1}{2}\tan\frac{\pi(n-2)}{2n}$$

For $n=4$, this is $1/2 = 0.5$; for $n=6$, it's $\sqrt{3}/2 = 0.8660\ldots$; for $n=5$, it's
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}} = 0.68819\ldots$$
This is *not* the average of $1/2$ and $\sqrt{3}/2$. It's *close* —the average is $0.6830\ldots$— but it's *not equal*. Extrapolating to arbitrary $n$ only compounds the error. $\square$

---

I'll note that [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2804939/409) avoids the messy calculation of the $5$-gon's apothem. By considering $n=12$, the inaccuracy of the construction is exposed using only the well-known elements of the $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangle.

Comment: @Blue This is all well and good -- *except* for the epilogue. First, the computation is not that messy. Second, as I said before, we all already know that the construction is problematic, so that it is not a question of accuracy. I wanted to know which step of the construction assumed an unjustified step, directly. Your first answer, by producing a contradiction, only shows what we all knew before -- that there is something wrong with the argument. However, it does not tell us where the fault is, neither does it tell us exactly what this fault is.

Comment: @Allawonder: Either accept the answer or don't. I no longer care to try and determine what will satisfy you.

Comment: @Blue It is not a question of what will satisfy me. Anybody can see that the first answer entirely misses the point of the question (and I entirely take the blame for that), so appending the epilogue to this more relevant answer seems to me to be, er..., what-shall-I-call-it? I hope you got the point, anyway. PS. The first sentence is tautological, so it is vacuously true.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Right off the bat, the first statement is false. It does lead to at least one regular polygon, for example the square whose side is $AB$ -- or you dispute this?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I have responded to a similar comment by the same person in the thread under the question.

Answer (score 5):

Let $E_n$ indicate the "engineer's circumcenter" of the $n$-gon with side $\overline{AB}$. Consider the case of $n=12$:

[image]

Although we might reasonably believe that $E_{12}$ *looks* too high to be the center of the polygon, we must admit that there *could* be some inaccuracies in the drawing. Fine. Let's define 
$$a :=|ME_4| = |MA| \qquad b := |ME_6| \qquad c := |E_5E_6| = \frac12(b-a)$$
By the engineer's construction, we find that
$$|ME_{12}| = |ME_{6}|+|E_6E_{12}| = b + 6 c = b + 3(b-a) = 4b - 3 a = a \left( 4 \sqrt{3} - 3 \right) \tag{1}$$ 
where I've incorporated $b/a = \sqrt3$, a well-known ratio from the $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangle. Yet, the diagram makes clear (in a way that doesn't depend upon accurate drawing) that the distance from $M$ to the $12$-gon's center is actually 
$$2 a + b = a\left(2 + \sqrt3\right) \tag{2}$$

Consequently, if the engineer's construction were correct, then we would have
$$4\sqrt{3} - 3 = 2 + \sqrt{3} \qquad\to\qquad \sqrt{3} = \frac{5}{3} \tag{3}$$
 which is, of course, untrue. (Proof: $(5/3)^2 = 25/9 \neq 3$. Or, you know, recall that $\sqrt3$ is irrational. Whatevs.) $\square$

Comment: Thank you. Although this answers the statement I quote in the OP, but I now see that it doesn't get at the heart of what I really wanted an explanation for (this is entirely my fault, of course, having failed to express myself properly). I shall edit the question accordingly. Thanks again for your expansive answer.

Comment: @Allawonder: Once you have received answers (especially multiple ones), you should not change the fundamental nature of the question. Rather, post a new one. You can edit the question to provide a link to the revised version (and you should also have a link in the new one that points back here).

Comment: Even if I notify all the respondents, as I plan to do upon revision?

Comment: No. By changing the question, you invalidate all the effort put in by the answerers, and you make the answers seem irrelevant when in fact they were perfectly relevant to the question asked. This is insulting to the responders and confusing to future readers. Ask another question. They're *free!* :)

Comment: Oh no, I do not intend to change exactly what I want to know, but to clarify some obscure points. What I really want to know is the incorrect step in the construction. You have shown that the construction is not accurate, but what I wanted was which of the steps was wrong. You have not addressed this at all.

Comment: Your first comment says "[T]his answers the statement I quote in the OP". I have *succeeded* in the task you provided. If "[w]hat [you] really want to know" is something other than what you asked ---and what I answered--- then a new question is required, because the intellectual transaction of the current question (asked, and answered) is complete.

Comment: BTW: As for which step is wrong: My comment to the question itself indicates that the construction of point $P$ (the ostensible center of the pentagon) is already inaccurate. **The construction fails at its very first substantive step.** (I consider construction of $45^\circ$ & $60^\circ$ angles merely preliminaries.) The center of the pentagon **is not** the midpoint of the centers of the square and hexagon; it's *passably* close at small scales —which is evidently why it's part of engineering lore— but it's *wrong*. Extrapolating to $n$-gons is unjustified, and merely compounds the error.

Comment: Your last comment comes closer to what I am really interested in. But why (independently, without arguing by contradiction as your answer would do) is it that $P$ is not the circumcentre of the regular pentagon of side $AB$.

Comment: *"But why [...] is it that $P$  is not the circumcentre of the regular pentagon of side $AB$."* That's like asking *"Why is it that $2+2$ is not $22$?"* It's just **not** ... and there's no reason to even *suspect* that it *should be*. The distance from the center to the side (of length $s$) of a regular $n$-gon (ie, the [apothem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apothem)) is given by $$\frac{s}{2}\tan\frac{\pi(n-2)}{2n}$$ For $n=4$, this is $s/2$; for $n=6$, it's $s\sqrt{3}/2$. For $n=5$, it's $$\frac{s}{2}\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}$$ which is **not** the average of $s/2$ and $s\sqrt{3}/2$.

Comment: There are two sentences by you in the comment immediately above this. The last effectively answers my question, I think (you could write it up as a separate answer and I'll accept), **even though** the former statement is plain wrong. It certainly seems intuitive (at least at first brush) that the point $P$ should be the centre of the pentagon, since one would expect it to be situated somewhere along $SH$, and intuition (unless finely disciplined) almost always indicates the arithmetic mean in such cases. I am grateful anyway. This has finally answered my question.

Comment: PS. Wow, an even better way to see this more immediately -- and thus **persuade** the doubting engineer back-of-the-envelope -- is to note that $\angle APB=72°$ is not the arithmetic mean of $\angle ASB=90°$ and $\angle AHB=60°$, as that suspect step in the construction assumes. Again, many thanks, sir.

Comment: @Allawonder: Um ... The midpoint construction **does not** correspond to the angular mean. (Converting length information to angle information is not nearly that simple. That's why we have trigonometry!) I don't believe that the construction —or any engineer worthy of the title—suggests that it does.

Comment: Oops, my bad! That doesn't, work *obviously* (pardon my blindness). Then one would have to use the apothegm argument. And no, I wasn't suggesting that the engineers in question do not know trigonometry (that leap was entirely my own fault). Incidentally, I noticed a comment directly under the question had suggested this apothegm argument too, but I had not noticed it until recently.  But of course, you would agree that the construction does suggest that the apothegm of the pentagon is the AM of that of the square and the hexagon, no?

Comment: @Allawonder: I doubt the construction's creator intended to make a claim of exactitude, but it's safe to say that construction asserts that the apothem of the pentagon is *very nearly approximated* by the arithmetic mean of the apothems of the square and the hexagon.

Comment: Well, along the lines of something you said above, the intention of the author is unavailable to me. What is available are their words, which clearly assert that it *is* the centre, and that the method is valid for all $n$-gons. They did not so much as mention that it is only an approximation.

Comment: @Allawonder: The only reason to believe that $P$ is the center of the pentagon seems to be an assumption that the center distances of $n$-gons for $n=4,5,6,\ldots$ "ought to be" an arithmetic progression. Blue's argument very nicely shatters that assumption, leaving _no_ reason that I can see for thinking $P$ ought to be the center of a pentagon either.

Answer (score 3):

If the reason given is 'this works by extrapolation', then ask them to extrapolate the other direction: construct a point $P'$ on the segment $SM$ with $|SP'|=|SP|$ and ask them if they think $P'$ is the center of the equilateral triangle $ABH$ (which it would have to be, by construction); it should be fairly clear that it's not (and this can easily be seen with a ruler and some quick measurements using only the given diagram, since one just has to measure the distances from $P'$ to $H$ and to $A$, say).

Alternately, you may be able to go one step further and argue that if this is the case, then surely the point $P''$ on $SM$ with $|SP''|=2|SP|$ must be $M$ itself, since it should be the center of the 'digon' on base $AB$, and then show that that's not the case.

Given either of these, it should be possible to argue that if the formula doesn't work exactly 'going down' then there should be no reason to believe that it works exactly 'going up'.

Comment: I have to thank you for the answer, but there are a couple of problems. In your first paragraph, you conclude that $P'$ is not the centre of the $\triangle ABH$, but it indeed seems to be, for the angle $AP'B=120°$, as expected. Also, one might object to your second paragraph by saying there is no polygon of less than three sides, so it is meaningless to extrapolate downwards beyond $P'$. Finally, it is not clear how the argument in your last paragraph goes, since this seems to work well for the constructible polygons. As I said in the question, where I suspect something to have crept in is...

Comment: ...in the bisection of $SH$, which seems reasonable but evidently doesn't produce correct results for the $7$-gon, without loss of generality. I shall edit the question to make clearer exactly where I think the problem may be with the construction. Thanks once again.

Comment: @Allawonder: Why do you say that $AP'B=120^\circ$?  That's certainly not obvious.  Indeed, by my calculations (following the method in David K's answer in the case $n=3$) that angle would be about $115.25^\circ$.  The construction described _doesn't_ work for all the constructible polygons; it _only_ works for the square and the hexagon.

Comment: @EricWofsey That's right. I realised this only later. I had been a bit too hasty.

Answer (score 2):

Let the length of $AB$ be $s.$ For integers $n \geq 4,$ let $C_n$ be the point given by the engineer's construction as the alleged circumcenter of an $n$-gon (polygon with $n$ sides) including side $AB.$
In particular, according to the construction, $S = C_4,$
$P = C_5,$ and $H = C_6.$

Let $h_n$ be the distance from $C_n$ to $M$ (where $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$). Let $\theta_n = \angle AC_nB,$ that is, $\theta_n$ is the angle at the apex of the isoceles triangle formed by the alleged circumcenter of the $n$-gon and the side of the desired $n$-gon.

Following the steps of the construction, we have $h_4 = \frac s2,$
$h_6 = \frac s2\sqrt3,$ and in general, for $n\geq 4,$
$$h_{n+1} = h_n + \frac12(h_6 - h_4) = h_n + \frac s4(\sqrt3 - 1).$$
We also have
$$\theta_n = 2 \arctan\left(\frac {s}{2h_n}\right).$$

Since the location of the alleged circumcenter is as far as the construction was given, let's suppose the next step to construct the $n$-gon is to replicate the isoceles triangle $\triangle AC_nB$ adjacent to the original triangle, for example, construct 
$\triangle A'C_nB$ so that $A'$ is on the opposite side of $BC_n$ from $A$
and $\triangle A'C_nB \cong \triangle AC_nB.$
Then $A'B$ is another side of the alleged $n$-gon that is supposed to be constructed by this method.
We then repeat this step until we have built all the sides of the $n$-gon.

If the construction is accurate, we should expect the sequence of sides to close upon itself when there are $n$ sides.
In fact, the sequence of sides will close exactly (forming an exact regular $n$-gon) if the apex angles of $n$ isoceles triangles fill in the entire circle around the center $C_n$, that is, if
$n\theta_n = 360 \text{ degrees}.$
But let's work out the values of $\theta_n$ (measured in degrees) in a few cases and see what actually happens:

\begin{array}{ccccc}
n & \dfrac{2h_n}{s} & \theta_n & n\theta_n & \dfrac{360}{\theta_n}\\ \hline
4 & 1 & 90 & 360 & 4 \\
5 & 1.366025404 & 72.41204623 & 362.0602311 & 4.971548503 \\
6 & 1.732050808 & 60 & 360 & 6 \\
7 & 2.098076211 & 50.96746918 & 356.7722842 & 7.063328939 \\
8 & 2.464101615 & 44.17732616 & 353.4186093 & 8.148976665 \\
9 & 2.830127019 & 38.9208091 & 350.2872819 & 9.249550775 \\
10 & 3.196152423 & 34.74731825 & 347.4731825 & 10.36051178 \\
11 & 3.562177826 & 31.36174493 & 344.9791943 & 11.47895312 \\
12 & 3.92820323 & 28.56475913 & 342.7771096 & 12.60294191 \\
13 & 4.294228634 & 26.21776217 & 340.8309082 & 13.73114905 \\
14 & 4.660254038 & 24.22181756 & 339.1054458 & 14.86263362 \\
15 & 5.026279442 & 22.50462422 & 337.5693633 & 15.99671234 \\
16 & 5.392304845 & 21.01223175 & 336.1957081 & 17.13287785 \\
17 & 5.758330249 & 19.70362898 & 334.9616927 & 18.27074598 \\
18 & 6.124355653 & 18.54712081 & 333.8481746 & 19.41002076 \\
19 & 6.490381057 & 17.51784696 & 332.8390923 & 20.55047066 \\
20 & 6.856406461 & 16.59604739 & 331.9209479 & 21.69191202 \\
\end{array}

The results are perfect for $n = 4$ and $n = 6.$

For $n = 5,$ we end up with two triangles overlapping by about two degrees at $C_5.$ That may be good enough for a line drawing, especially if we make sure to erase any parts of the overlapping sides that appear to be outside the pentagon.

For $n = 7,$ we end up with a gap of more than three degrees after constructing the seventh isoceles triangle. Again, for a line drawing that's merely for looking at, we can fudge the result and just extend the two sides adjacent to the gap until they meet.
For $n = 8,$ the gap is more than six degrees;
for $n = 9,$ the gap is getting close to ten degrees.
I wonder when the people who look at the resulting line drawings will start to notice the discrepancy?

Going onward in the table, watch the values of $360/\theta_n,$
which indicate how many of the constructed isoceles triangles will "fit"
around the point $C_n.$ The integer part of  $360/\theta_n$
represents how many triangles will fit without overlapping at all,
and the fractional part
represents how much of the apex angle of one more such triangle will "fit"
between the others without overlapping.
For example, the value of $360/\theta_5$ indicates that there is a slight overlap when we construct the fifth side of the alleged pentagon.

What this column shows is that if we perform the construction accurately,
when we have constructed the $11$th side of the alleged $11$-gon there is a gap almost large enough to fit half of another isoceles triangle.
The alleged $15$-gon has very nearly enough space to fit a $16$th side,
and the alleged $16$-gon has space for a $17$th side with room to spare.

The discrepancies just get worse as we try more sides.
The alleged $23$-gon winds up with at least $25$ sides
(two more than it is supposed to have).
The construction that is supposed to give $30$ sides gives $33.$

You cannot fix these errors by drawing more carefully.
The errors are inherent in the trigonometry of the construction.
For come purposes, your engineer may not care about the two-degree overlap of the pentagon construction, but surely it is not acceptable to get $17$ sides when you wanted $16$ or $33$ when you wanted $30.$

If we're going to go to so much trouble to get such bad results,
we might as well just use a calculator to find the inradius of the polygon,
lay off that distance along the perpendicular bisector of $AB,$
and use a protractor to construct the central angles around that point.

What this construction *might* be good for is as an approximate shortcut for the construction of the  pentagon (for which an exact method also exists),
the heptagon, and (if accuracy really doesn't matter that much) perhaps the octagon. Even so, does anyone make engineering drawings with classical instruments nowadays, or is this just a historical curiosity?

---

The preceding part of this answer shows that the method gets results that
(I hope) would be regarded as bad even for rough-drawing purposes,
but it does not point out an error in any particular step
(other than the fact that at the end we have the wrong result).
So let's consider what kind of result a *correct* construction would have to get.

If the side of a regular $n$-gon is $s,$ the angle subtended by that side
at the circumcenter of the polygon is $\alpha_n,$
and the inradius of the polygon is $r_n,$ then
$$
r_n = \frac s2 \cot\left( \frac{\alpha_n}{2} \right).
$$
But $\alpha_n = \frac{2\pi}{n}$ (that is, $\frac{360}{n}$ when we measure the angle  in degrees).
The engineer's construction implicitly says that $r_n$ is a linear function of $n,$ at least for $n \geq 4,$ which is to say that $\cot(\pi/n)$ is a linear function of $n.$
That's simply wrong; if it were correct, trigonometric functions would be much easier to calculate than is actually the case.
The claimed linear relationship  is only approximately true, and even the approximation is only good over a small interval of values.

So the incorrect step specifically is when we lay off a distance of some multiple of $HP$ as if $\cot(\pi/n)$ were a linear function of $n.$
It's a decent approximation (for some purposes) for the first few multiples of $HP,$ but really only for a *few* multiples, and then it quickly gets worse until you end up constructing the wrong polygon altogether.

Comment: Thank you, even though a large segment of your answer seems unnecessary as it is irrelevant (the engineer may already know it is inaccurate, so that that wasn't my question), so that the last segment might have sufficed well as it immediately shows that the function connecting the inradius to the number of sides is nonlinear as the construction assumes. Thanks once again. The question is now closed.

Answer (score 1):

The distance from the midpoint of the side of a regular polygon to the circum-center (the apothem), does not increase linearly with an increase in the number of sides. Forty years of engineering and I never heard of this crude construction before.

Comment: Concerning your last sentence, see, for example, Parker and Pickup, *Engineering Drawing,* 3rd edition, pp. 11, 12.

Comment: I remember that book and even had classes given by Parker, I believe. Well, that was around 1970, in Bristol England. This was back in the day when pi = 22/7. These rough estimates were fine for aircraft lofting, but not so good for high precision jet turbines.

Comment: Many engineering and technology schools still train their students by that book. My question was about how to convince such people (contra the authors, e.g.) that there is something the matter with the construction.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, the apothem does not increase linearly with an in crease in the number of sides. For a circle, the radius increases linearly with a linear increase in circumference. But chord length/arc length ratio varies so the linearity is lost. I can see how they could sell it as a close approximation as that's all it is. Pickup and Parker, the authors, must be long gone by now.

Comment: Do you honestly think engineers believe $\pi = \frac {22}7$?  That they don't get that everything they do is an approximation?

Comment: Of course I don't, but I can tell you from experience, I've seen a lot of parts made that didn't go together for want of a better understanding of geometry.

Comment: @PhilH But should that matter? If you checked the construction again, you would see that the argument does not assume linearity between the apothegm and the number of sides. What it does assume is that the sequence of apothegms is strictly increasing, which looks reasonable. This is the main problem here. To deconstruct what makes the argument look so intuitive and logical at first sight.